# how to write c++ codes in ros, for analysing kinect depth datas?

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im trying to write 3d computer vision in ros in c++, but it looks like c++ in ros is little different, so what is the important neceasary lines to add in c++ code for this, or what is basic format of ros c++, for kinect?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234267/how-to-write-c++-codes-in-ros,-for-analysing-kinect-depth-datas?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's conceptually the same as in Python, just syntactically different. Include your message headers and parse the data using a [c++ subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B).

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-05-12**:
The answer from @curranw is correct... a PointCloud2 message is just like any other message. Subscribe to the data and work with it. However I will point out that it seems a huge majority of people working with C++ and point clouds tend to use [PCL](http://pointclouds.org/) and `pcl_ros`